# Cell array method return

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return, cell

I know in methods when returning it would be the type you want returned.

```
public int numbers(){
    return number;
}

public String sentence(){
    return sentence;
}
```

but what if it's a `Cell[]`, what would be the return type? I want to return the entire `Cell[]` from a method.

Comment: What language is this? (assuming Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not

```
public Cell[] cells(){
    return cells;
}
```

Comment: ohhhhhhh! yes it worked. incredible how obvious an answer is when given. thank you